# .NET runtime error while excuting .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, compatibility

I have compiled my code to SupportProject.dll using **.Net Framework 4**. I'm using this dll in my another project Target. But while executing the project Target I'm getting below error

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or asse
>       mbly 'SupportProject, Version=1.3.8325.1453, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or
>        one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the cur
>       rently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
>       File name: 'SupportProject, Version=1.3.8325.1453, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nu
>       ll'

Machine on which I'm executing Target project has **.net version 4.0**
TIA.

Comment: This is probably because of a mismatch in Architectures, e.g. an x64 process using and x86 library

Comment: Application where you are using this SupprotProject.dll is targeted for .Net version lesser than 4.0.

Comment: @PankajKapare I'm compiling target project in .NET 4. But there are some errors introduced. These are related to classes in my SupportProject.dll. Though they are present there in SupportProject but Target project is not able to find. TIA [I hope I hv conveyed my problem :)]

Comment: @DaveShaw Plz respond to my above comment. TIA

Comment: What is the application architecture set to for both projects ?

Comment: @DaveShaw both are x64. I googled for COM but what i got is code licensed by microsoft. COM for supporting .NET4 dlls in .NET 2. As i mentioned in my earlier comment I also tried compiling project in .NET 4 but errors.